# Database Some tables backup and restore issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, backup, database-backups

May someone please share your expertise.

i was taking a backup of couple of tables with data. `(Script Data – True)`.

but when i tried to open the script , its throwing error as `OPERATION COULD NOT COMPLETE`

may any one please help me what could be possible reason for it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: which table throwing exception ?? or all having issue ?

Comment: @NazirUllah: all having issue

Comment: how you take backup , is backup completed successfully ?

Comment: @NazirUllah: i used generate script wizard. it completed successfully

Comment: ok now how you open the script , backup can't open directly but you should restore it into database

Comment: @NazirUllah: Thanks Nazir.